# why can't DTDs specify the order of grandchild nodes?

Tags: xml, dtd

```
<nodes>
    <x><a/></x>
    <x><b/></x>
    <x><c/></x>
    <x><d/></x>
</nodes>
```

within `<nodes>` there should be a `<x><a/></x>` followed by a `<x><b/></x>` and `<x><c/></x>`  and `<x><d/></x>` in that order.

I want the DTD to be sort of like this:

```
<!ELEMENT x (a|b|c|d)>
<!ELEMENT nodes (x(a),x(b),x(c),x(d))>
```

Is it possible for DTDs to specify the order of grandchild nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't specify the order of grandchildren. You're only defining the content model of the element you're declaring.

You'd be better off eliminating `x`:

```
<!ELEMENT nodes (a,b,c,d)>
```

XML:

```
<nodes>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
  <d/>
</nodes>
```